# Output hash-table without @{var=...} when parsing .xml files in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm new to Powershell, and trying to parse a .xml file using the code below:

```
[xml] $Alloc_macro = get-content ".\Allocation_macro.xml"
$newlist = @()
foreach ($layer1 in $Alloc_macro.dmob.module.macro.block[4].block)
{
    $condition = ($layer1 | select condition)
    foreach ($layer2 in $layer1.for)
    {
        $var = ($layer2 | select var)
        $in = ($layer2 | select in)
        $newlist += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{ condition = $condition; var = $var; in = $in }
    }
}
$newlist
```

Here's the result:

```
condition                                             var                                                  in
---------                                             ---                                                  --
@{condition=@[AllocationFlag]}                        @{var=AllocationNumber}                              @{in=*[EQ](##PersonalNonPersonal##,"Personal",@[A...
@{condition=*[NOT](@[AllocationFlag])}
```

My question is, can I get something like this:

```
condition                                             var                                                  in
---------                                             ---                                                  --
@[AllocationFlag]                                     AllocationNumber                              *[EQ](##PersonalNonPersonal##,"Personal",@[A...
*[NOT](@[AllocationFlag])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
$condition = ($layer1 | select condition)
```

to this

```
$condition = ($layer1 | select -expand condition)
```

Comment: Awesome! Really appreciate your help!